# Map values in column to values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I want to replace certain values with corresponding values in SQL. I cannot create a cross-reference table. The values can be specified in 'txt' or 'properties' file in my application

I looked at `CASE` statement but I have 200 replacements to make for which `CASE` is not sufficient

```
SELECT dummy FROM TestTable;
```

In my answer if I get `LOT_NUMBER` I want to replace it with `Lot Number` or if I get `LOT_NUMBER_XREF` I want to replace it with `Lot Number Cross-Reference`

```
dummy
LOT_NUMBER
LOT_NUMBER_XREF
```

to be replaced with

```
dummy
Lot Number
Lot Number Cross-Reference
```

Comment: Give us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Simplify! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Create a cross-reference table with columns for the old and new values, then join to it.

Comment: @EricBrandt - I cannot create a cross-reference table. The values can be specified in 'txt' or 'properties' file in my application. I just added info to question.

Comment: @raj247: Then create a table and fill it with the values from the files.

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have many different values to replace, you should create a table to store the mapping of old values to new values. Then you can join that table in your query.

The below SQL replaces the old value with the new value (or leaves it as is if no translation was defined) :

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(m.new_value, t.value)
FROM 
    table t
    LEFT JOIN mapping_table m 
        ON t.value = m.old_value
```

For a limited number of values to translate you can CASE. or maybe a CTE with UNION :

```
WITH mapping_table AS (
    SELECT 'LOT_NUMBER' AS old_value, 'Lot Number' AS new_value
    SELECT 'LOT_NUMBER_XREF', 'Lot Number Cross-Reference'
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE(m.new_value, t.value)
FROM 
    table t
    LEFT JOIN mapping_table m 
        ON t.value = m.old_value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use cross-reference table, use  (you'll have to generate it in your app) sub-query or cte instead!
CTE:

```
with mapping as (
 select 'LOT_NUMBER' as old_value, 'Lot Number' as new_value
 union all select 'LOT_NUMBER_XREF', 'Lot Number Cross-Reference'
)
select 
 t.value,
 coalesce(m.new_value, 'none') as new_value
from tbl_your_table t
left join mapping m on t.value = m.old_value
```

Or SubQuery:

```
select 
 t.value,
 coalesce(m.new_value, 'none') as new_value
from tbl_your_table t
left join (
 select 'LOT_NUMBER' as old_value, 'Lot Number' as new_value
 union all select 'LOT_NUMBER_XREF', 'Lot Number Cross-Reference'
) m on t.value = m.old_value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something generic like `_` charecter then what you can do is use `LIKE` operator and

```
             SELECT replace(dummy,'_',' ') from table where 
             dummy like '%_%'   -- check generic regex
```

then, use `CASE WHEN` on top of this with `DUMMY` `IN(X,REF) Then REPLACE(DUMMY,'X',CROSS)` likewise for the others as well this will reduce the no of cases.

The thing is just check the generalised terms and their replacements store it `IN` clause prefiltering the most general ones. If the count is still large you need a temporary table for lookup reference like array in other programming languages